# IOS - Storing value in a Static Variable like php Sessions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that needs to keep hold of how many people have joined a room, my problem is keeping a hold of this value. I need to increment this value by one every time the user joins. So i need to check that the room is not full.

I have been thinking of using sessions and keeping track of this value in php, but is there another way natively, so my question is how do i retain or persist this value?

I tried this running on two phones but the value is always 1 when the global value (myData) should be 2 when the second phone runs the app:

```
 myData = myData + 1;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myData] forKey:@"myData"];

NSLog(@"%d",myData);
```

Comment: counting of room members didn't help? if offline members should be counted too, then this count definitely should be stored on server as a room property (bad way) or as a room members list (preferred way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to synchronise information between the devices in your case, you should update the data using your server (or how you handle the networking between the devices and rooms etc.)

For example if you install the app in a new phone, it should firstly fetch the value from your server and save the NSUserDefaults so that it can be synchronised.
However, with this way, I don't think you need to store data in the phone, so you can directly use information from server to check the room fullness etc. Storing as NSUserDefaults looked unnecessary to me.

I hope I got the question and your app right.